# Pytest Parametrize

Tags: python, pytest

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", [0, 1])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("y", [2, 3])
def test_func(x, y):
    pass
```

As Expected when I execute above code , I will get combinations as follows:

iteration-1) x=0 , y=2,   iteration-2) x=1 , y=2 ,iteration-3) x=0 , y=3, 4) x=1 , y=3

But is there any way to select/limit combinations or print as follows

iteration-1) x=0 , y=2,   iteration-2) x=0 , y=3 ,iteration-3) x=1 , y=2, 4) x=1 , y=3

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The most simple solution would be to use only one `parametrize` decorator

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x,y", [(0,2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3)])
def test_func(x, y):
    pass
```

Comment: If you want to be fancy you could define that list as `list(itertools.product([0,1],[2,3]))`. Then you don't have to manually define it and can change easily how you construct it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order of parameter:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("y", [2, 3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", [0, 1])
def test_func(x, y):
    pass
```

It will give the expected iterations

1) x=0 , y=2, iteration-2) x=0 , y=3 ,iteration-3) x=1 , y=2, 4) x=1 , y=3